# Assigning a data parameter to a Jade mixin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug, templating

Here is my mixin in mixins.jade

```
mixin link(url, name)
  a(href='#{data.url}', title=name)&attributes(attributes)= name
```

my data in data.json

```
{
    "facebook": "fb.com",
    "twitter": "tt.com",
}
```

here is the mixin called in the template

```
+link('facebook', 'Go to facebook')(class="social-link")
```

the processing with gulp in gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {

  gulp.src(srcDir + '/html/template.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      locals: {
        data: data,
        pretty: true
      }
    }))
    .pipe(rename('intermediate.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(srcDir + '/html'))
});
```

end result gives undefined value

```
<a href="undefined" title="Go to facebook" class="social-link">Go to facebook</a>
```

Can't find a way yet to be able to call my data in the mixin. I know the data is working because if I give data.facebook in the mixin (for instance) instead of data.url, then I will have the correct url rendered.

Also doesn't work : 
    mixin link(url, name)
      a(href='#{data.'+url+'}', title=name)&attributes(attributes)= name

it renders

```
<a href="#{data.webversion}">
```

instead of `<a href="fb.com">`

Answer (score 0):

What if you use

```
mixin link(url, name)
  a(href=url, title=name)&attributes(attributes)= name
```

edit: or maybe

```
mixin link(url, name)
  a(href='#{data[url]}', title=name)&attributes(attributes)= name
```

Comment: if I do that, my template will look like this   `+link('#{data.facebook}', 'Go to facebook')(class="social-link")` thats too much words for my taste

Comment: will try your second suggestion